# Craftercms - Social: Is it possible to specify which user attributes the "create comment" API should retrieve?

Tags: crafter-cms

Is there a way to specify which user attributes are retrieved in the response of the "create comment" API call?

I mean:

"user":{

```
 "attributes":{
 }
```

}

The call I am talking about is documented here:
https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/projects/social/api/v3/ugc/comments/create.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to set a system wide way to control the profile properties returned for every API:

- Edit `$TOMCAT_HOME/shared/classes/crafter/social/extension/server-config.properties`
- Add `studio.social.system.profileAgg.attributesToReturn=displayName,avatarLink,socialContexts,notificationLocale,autoWatch,defaultFrequency,isAlwaysAnonymous,ADD_HERE_ANY_EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES`
- Restart the server.